# Change name of route:resource parameter

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, routes

I have this route:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'admin'], function () {
  Route::resource('backoffice/home', 'Backoffice\Home');
  Route::resource('backoffice/ProductBasic', 'Backoffice\ProductBasic');
});
```

Laravel by default uses "ProductBasic" as parameter. As can be requested with

```
Request::route()->parameters();
```

The return on dd() will be

```
array:1 [▼
"ProductBasic" => "1"
]
```

I would like to adjust of every var. How can i do that while still using Route::resource as a method of creating my routes.

Edit:
Goals is to use the parameter outside a controller, in a composer. By using 1 parameter for a group of routes (and another for another group...) i can create a dynamic menu.

```
If(isset(parameter)){
    use parameter value to do something
}
```

I know i can pass parameters to the view and access the values in the view, but i think it's a cleaner solution this way.

Comment: Maybe with optional parameter - https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-parameters ? 

Example:

Route::resource('backoffice/home/{function?}');

This is what you want?

Comment: Are you asking about how to transport variables from your route to your controller?

Comment: @denis: i don't think that works when using a resource route.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin no, i want to tranport the variables to a view composer. I did edit my question to clearify.